# GitHub Windows "loading commits failed"

Tags: git, github-for-windows

Out of nowhere I got the error "loading commits failed" and it asked me to debug it using the console. I tried typing `git log` and I got the error "fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'" pretty much anything I try to do causes this error.

Seems to be a bug with GitHub Windows Client, I definitely wasn't doing anything weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the branch I was working on exploded.

In `C:\Users\Farzher\Documents\GitHub\project\.git\refs\heads` I found my branch `dev.lock` I just renamed it to `dev` and everything was back to normal!